# Error : '\u001f', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character

Tags: c#, rss, xmlreader

I want to read RSS,

I use this code but get error `'\u001f', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character.`

```
   XmlReader reader = new MyXmlReader(url);
   var feed = await Task.Run(() => SyndicationFeed.Load(reader));
```

I use this

```
var client = new WebClient();
var feedAsString = client.DownloadString(url);
feedAsString = feedAsString.Replace((char)(0x1F), Convert.ToChar(""));
using (XmlReader reade = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(feedAsString)),
new XmlReaderSettings()
 {
                    IgnoreWhitespace = true,
                    CheckCharacters = true,
                    CloseInput = true,
                    IgnoreComments = true,
                    IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true
                }))
            {
                var feed = await Task.Run(() => SyndicationFeed.Load(reade));
                reade.Close();
                if (feed != null && feed.Items.Any())
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
```

but get error `String must be exactly one character long.`

Comment: Well, `Convert.ToChar` will not magically make an empty string legal as character.

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToChar` method requires you to pass single character and it cannot accept empty string. In order to remove 0x1F symbol from your string you need to use `string.Replace(string, string)` overload instead `string.Replace(char, char)`.

So in order to remove all occurrences of 0x1F symbol you could use following code:

```
feedAsString = feedAsString.Replace(((char)0x1F).ToString(), "");
```

EDIT:

As Nyerguds pointed out we can further simplify and use unicode char directly in string:

```
feedAsString = feedAsString.Replace("\u001F", "");
```

Comment: No need to do all the casting and converting there. The unicode notation from the error message works inside a string: `.Replace("\u001F", "")`

Comment: @Nyerguds Totally forgot about that. I have updated my answer, thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this code , i get error `: 'Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.'`

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, it is ok

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
            {
                using (var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(url))
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream.Result))
                    {
                        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                        {
                            var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
                            if (feed != null && feed.Items.Any())
                                return true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```